# Help with a displayed formula with a determinant

Tags: math-mode

```
\begin{center}
$
 \delta = 
 \left|
\begin{array}{cc} 
1 & x_{0} & x_{0}^{2} & ... & x_{0}^{n} \\ 
1 & x_{1} & x_{1}^{2} & ... & x_{1}^{n} \\
............................ \\
1 & x_{n} & x_{n}^{2} & ... & x_{n}^{n} \\ 
\end{array}
\right|

 = {\displaystyle \prod_{0\leq j < i \leq n} (x_{i} - x_{j})} $
\end{center}
```

It does not work! How can I do that `\delta` = Vandermond Determinant = `\prod`?

Comment: Don't you use a trivial title please.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 18):

Remove the blank line, which is not allowed in math environments. Also you're defining an array with two columns and use five of them.

However you're not using the right tools: for a displayed equation use `\[...\]` and not `center`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % always load it for math

\begin{document}

\[
\delta =
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & x_{0} & x_{0}^{2} & \dots & x_{0}^{n} \\ 
1 & x_{1} & x_{1}^{2} & \dots & x_{1}^{n} \\
\hdotsfor{5} \\
1 & x_{n} & x_{n}^{2} & \dots & x_{n}^{n}
\end{vmatrix}
=
\prod_{0\leq j < i \leq n} (x_{i} - x_{j})
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that my answer was posted about 6 seconds before this answer. :-)

Comment: A hint too an introduction would be useful.

Comment: I've never seen `\hdotsfor` before... every day something new to learn :)

Comment: @cgnieder `\hdotsfor` is in Mike Spivak's `amstex.tex` (1985). You've never read “The Joy of TeX”, I guess. `;-)`

Answer (score 13):

### Suggestions

- Use `{}` only for grouping more than one character. `x_{0}^{n}` can be simplified by using `x_0^n` as it will increase readability.
- Use  `\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\` rather than `..............`. Because `............` is not used by most mathematicians.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in your production
\begin{align*}
\delta 
&= 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & x_0 & x_0^2 & \cdots & x_0^n \\ 
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^n \\ 
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=
\prod_{0\leq j < i \leq n} (x_{i} - x_{j})
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Note

The following parts in the code above are used only to generate the image above. You might  NOT need it in your production. Be careful!

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in your production
```

Comment: I believe that showing the example to a new user with `standalone` and strange assignments is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

A few notes:

1. We use `amsmath`'s `vmatrix` instead of a `\left|` `array` `\right` approach for the matrix.
2. We also use the `equation` environment, centering inline math (`$`) is not the best idea.
3. If you do not want the equation numbered, use `equation*` instead.
4. Also, one should not use `.....`, use `\dots`, `\vdots` and friends instead.

You can use the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    \delta = \begin{vmatrix}
      1       & x_{0} & x_{0}^{2} & \dots & x_{0}^{n} \\ 
      1       & x_{1} & x_{1}^{2} & \dots & x_{1}^{n} \\
      \vdots  & \vdots&  \vdots   &       & \vdots    \\
      1       & x_{n} & x_{n}^{2} & \dots & x_{n}^{n} \\ 
    \end{vmatrix} = \prod_{0\leq j < i \leq n} (x_{i} - x_{j})
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]